# UNITY: Google Play Authentication failed when download from Google Play store

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

using android version 6.0, play-games-plugin-for-unity v0.9.38a, unity 5.6.0f3.

**Build and run direct** from **PC** to **android phone** is **working**. Means my setting in google play console and unity is correct.

But after i **remove the apps** and **download from google play store**, the google pay Authentication **did not work** at all.

I'm so curious why direct from PC works but download from **google play store** cannot? 
Anyone have this same problem?

Here is the code.

```
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;

.....
    void Start () {
        // Create client configuration
        PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new 
            PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder()
            .Build();

        // Enable debugging output (recommended)
        PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;

        // Initialize and activate the platform
        PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();


        PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate(SignInCallback, false);


    }

    public void SignInCallback(bool success) {
        if (success) {
            txtUserName.text = Social.localUser.userName;
            isSignIn = true;
            txtSignInOut.text = "Sign Out";
            btnShowTopScore.SetActive (true);
        } else {
            txtUserName.text = "";
            isSignIn = false;
            btnShowTopScore.SetActive (false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: hope this will help, it solved my problem.
check out :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153675/google-play-games-service-error-not-authorized-when-rollout-for-beta-unity3/44235859#44235859

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Github issues, I had finally solve the solution. The problem is happen with Google app sign in.

From https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1754#issuecomment-304581707

What I did:

Google Play Console -> Select your app -> Release Management -> App signing -> App signing certificate : copy SHA-1 (dont copy word 'SHA1:')

open console.developers.google.com , select your project -> credentials -> OAuth 2.0 client IDs -> Edit OAuth client -> Signing-certificate fingerprint -> replace the old SHA1 with copied SHA1 ->save.

open you game, you should get sign in -> email selection -> select testers email. Google Play Games Services should work fine now.

and here is blog in case someone need it.

https://kyokurosagi.blogspot.my/2017/05/unity-local-login-with-unity-android.html