# Google Play Services work from APK but not from Play Store

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-services

**UPDATE: Found solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44240936/12636661**

Google Play Service work when app installed from .apk, but don't work when app installed from Google Play Store.

I have Google Play Services configured in my Unity project and when I install my app to the phone with "Build and run" or to any other phone through .apk file it works just fine, authorization works normally, I see "Welcome %username%", cloud savings and loadings are also good.

But when I post the very same build (as a bundle) to Play Store (in closed beta status) and install from there, I see only "Connecting to Play Games..." text, the green rotating circle blinks a couple of times in the center and none of GS functions work.

What may be the problem?