# Google play game services only working in alpha and beta

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, keystore, leaderboard

I have my apk signed with the SHA-1 google upload key and when I deploy it in alpha or beta version it works fine and logs in google and shows leaderboards.

The problem it's when i click deploy it on production then the google services don't connect I see the google play popup trying to connect but it fails.

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: After 2 days i found this solution! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153675/google-play-games-service-error-not-authorized-when-rollout-for-beta-unity3/44235859#44235859