# What's wrong with ShowLeaderboardUI();

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Google Services for leaderboard in my game. It's not authenticate on start, should show leaderboard by clicking on button, but it's not showing anything.
How I could solve it?

My authenticate script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;


public class Auth : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static PlayGamesPlatform platform;

    private void Start() {
        if (platform == null) {
            PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().Build();
            PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
            PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;

            platform = PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
        }

        Social.Active.localUser.Authenticate(succes => {
            if (succes) {
                Debug.Log("ENTER GOOGLE SERVICES");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Leaderboard button script

```
using UnityEngine;
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;

public class Lead : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const string leaderboard = "Cg******";

    public void OpenLead() {
        Social.ReportScore(14, leaderboard, (bool succes) => {
            if (succes) {
                Debug.Log("SUCCESFUL ADDED");
            }
        });
        Social.ShowLeaderboardUI();
    }
}
```

I also saw a lot of this questions on the internet, but it's didn't help. I use latest play-games-plugin-for-unity, also tried

```
PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ShowLeaderboardUI(leaderboard);
```

and

```
if ((((PlayGamesLocalUser) Social.localUser).Email != null) || (((PlayGamesLocalUser) Social.localUser).Email != ""))
```

Comment: use `logcat` to get the logs, there should be some errors on the logs.

Comment: I found this error in logcat: [Play Games Plugin DLL] 09/30/19 14:11:42 +03:00 DEBUG: Starting Auth Transition. Op: SIGN_IN status: ERROR_NOT_AUTHORIZED. How I could solve it?

Comment: Check these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153675/google-play-games-service-error-not-authorized-when-rollout-for-beta-unity3 and https://forum.unity.com/threads/google-play-games-sign-in-error_not_authorized-solved.433795/